# How Would I use Jquery to add a multiplier to a predefined number?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use a drop down menu to apply a multiplier to a predetermined number. Here is the HTML code but I am inexperienced in Jquery.

```html
<body>
<span class="Door">
    <select name="Amount" class="wpcf7-form-control  wpcf7-select">
        <option value="1.1">Traditional_doors</option>
        <option value="1.1">Duo_doors</option>
        <option value="1.3">cottage_doors</option>
        <option value="1.4">Modern_doors</option>
        <option value="1.4">Diamante_doors</option>
 <option value="1.5">Handmade_shaker_doors</option>
 <option value="1.6">Beaded_classic_or_victorian_doors</option>
    </select>
</spa>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the value of the option or add it somewhere else?

Comment: @Difster Sorry should have clarified, I want to define a value and apply a multiplier on drop down selection.

Answer (score 1):

Get the value of select on change, multiply it with the number and print it

```js
var a = 10;
$('select').change(function() {
  a = a * $(this).val();
  console.log(a);
  a=10;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <span class="Door">
    <select name="Amount" class="wpcf7-form-control  wpcf7-select">
        <option value="1.1">Traditional_doors</option>
        <option value="1.1">Duo_doors</option>
        <option value="1.3">cottage_doors</option>
        <option value="1.4">Modern_doors</option>
        <option value="1.4">Diamante_doors</option>
 <option value="1.5">Handmade_shaker_doors</option>
 <option value="1.6">Beaded_classic_or_victorian_doors</option>
    </select>
</span>
```